# WPF multiple selection of a nested datagrid into a list

Tags: wpf, datagrid, nested, selection

I’m trying to select multiple rows in my nested datagrid and put the rows into a list or at least get all the first column values of the selected rows, but I can’t find anywhere on the web that details how to do that. Is it even possible?

Can someone show me a quick example?

Answer (score 0):

```
YourDataGrid.SelectedItems;
```

This will get you all the rows you have selected in code behind, To multi select use Ctrl key while selecting and don't forget to allow Extended selection mode(I guess its the default), put this `SelectionMode="Extended"` in your xaml.

And you can access rows like this

```
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)YourDataGrid.SelectedItems[0];
```

And you can access Cells like this

```
row["ColumnName"];
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you but that only gets me the rows I selected on the parent grid, not my nested one...

Comment: Can you share some code please, so I can understand your exact situation.